# add value of nested dictionary if key exists

Tags: python

I am having a code. I took it from stack overflow only

below is the code

```
def does_nested_key_exists(dictionary, nested_key, keys=None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = []

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key == nested_key:
            return True, '.'.join(keys)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            keys.append(key)
            return does_nested_key_exists(value, nested_key, keys)
    return False, ""

menu = {'dinner':
            {'chicken':'good',
             'beef':'average',
             'vegetarian':{
                   'tofu':'good',
                   'salad':{
                            'caeser':'bad',
                            'italian':'average'}
                   },
             'pork':'bad'}
        }
```

What I need is if suppose a new key suppose `green_veg` having parent as `vegetarian` exists (as it is), I need to add the `green_veg` key under same parent key `vegetarian`. Suppose if parent key does not exist, i want to add to main dict like direct key for dict menu

How can i achieve this

Comment: What is the depth of having dictionary as a value?

Comment: not sure of the depth. It can go any level down.

Comment: if depth is unclear, where are you supposed to add the new item if the parent is nowhere present.

Comment: at the main level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the two examples:

1. `{"green_veg": "bad"}` with parent `vegetarian`, where the parent is present in the dictionary named `menu`.
2. `{"green_veg": "bad"}` with parent `greens`, where the parent is not present in the dictionary named `menu`.
3. Process examples are also given.

Here is the code:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.parents = []

    def fun(self, dikt: dict, find_key, new_key):
        if find_key in dikt:
            dikt[find_key][new_key] = {}
            return True
        f = False
        for key, value in dikt.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                f = f or self.fun(value, find_key, new_key)
        return f

    def call(self, dikt: dict, find_key, new_key):
        p = self.fun(dikt, find_key, new_key)
        if not p:
            dikt[new_key] = {}
```

---

Example 1 (from question)

```py
menu = {
    "dinner": {
        "chicken": "good",
        "beef": "average",
        "vegetarian": {
            "tofu": "good",
            "salad": {"caeser": "bad", "italian": "average"},
        },
        "pork": "bad",
    }
}
print(menu)
Solution().call(menu, "vegetarian", "green_veg")
print(menu)
Solution().call(menu, "greens", "green_veg")
print(menu)
```

Here is the output:

```py
{'dinner': {'chicken': 'good', 'beef': 'average', 'vegetarian': {'tofu': 'good', 'salad': {'caeser': 'bad', 'italian': 'average'}}, 'pork': 'bad'}}
{'dinner': {'chicken': 'good', 'beef': 'average', 'vegetarian': {'tofu': 'good', 'salad': {'caeser': 'bad', 'italian': 'average'}, 'green_veg': {}}, 'pork': 'bad'}}
{'dinner': {'chicken': 'good', 'beef': 'average', 'vegetarian': {'tofu': 'good', 'salad': {'caeser': 'bad', 'italian': 'average'}, 'green_veg': {}}, 'pork': 'bad'}, 'green_veg': {}}
```

---

Example 2 (from comments)

```py
menu = {}
print(menu)
Solution().call(menu, "None", "p1")
Solution().call(menu, "p1", "p2")
Solution().call(menu, "p2", "p3")
print(menu)
```

Here is the output:

```py
{}
{'p1': {'p2': {'p3': {}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for something else

Comment: can you please elaborate more on it.

Comment: yes  I am typing

Comment: I need something like this: Solution().call(menu, "parent", "new_key"). If parent exists then add to the parent and if not add to the menu key not dinner key. and value also we can have like empty dict

Comment: like i am basically parsing a process id tree. suppose P1 is the parent process and P2 is the child process then I need dict as {P1: {P2: {}}. and now P3 is the child for Process P2. so it will become {P1: {P2: {P3: {}}

Comment: is it bit more clear now?

Comment: value we can mark it empty

Comment: Please go through the new solution

Answer (score 1):

```
menu = {
    "dinner": {
        "chicken": "good",
        "beef": "average",
        "vegetarian": {
            "tofu": "good",
            "salad": {"caeser": "bad", "italian": "average"},
        },
        "pork": "bad",
    }
}

def menuItems(dict,type,target,keys):
    if(target in dict[type].keys()):
        dict[type][target][keys[0]]=keys[1]
    else:
        dict[type][keys[0]]=keys[1]

menuItems(menu,'dinner','vegitarian',['green_veg','bad'])
print(menu)
```

**output:**

```
{'dinner': {'chicken': 'good', 'beef': 'average', 'vegetarian': {'tofu': 'good', 'salad': {'caeser': 'bad', 'italian': 'average'}}, 'pork': 'bad', 'green_veg': 'bad'}}
```

**theory:**

```
  ->check weather the key exist or not in parent
  ->if exist create a new key with value in that key
  ->else create a key in parent which is type in above code
```

I think it may help you to understand the basic concept of dictionaries in python.